# Fix ufw blocking ssh access, but one port is open

Tags: networking, ssh

I was trying to setup syncthing to sync my code between my mac and a remote VM and so installed ufw on the VM. I successfully got both the machines to be in sync, but after logging out of the ssh terminal, I'm no longer able to ssh into my VM. I think ufw is blocking my ssh connection into the machine. Any help would be really appreciated. Please note that I enabled syncthing on ufw, so 22000/TCP and 21027/UDP should be allowed, is it possible to tunnel through that port and fix my ssh?

Comment: No, not unless you specifically set up ssh to listen on those ports. Default is 22, so I'm afraid you will need to acquire access another way in order to allow 22/ssh. I suggest that in the future you create a permissive ufw script and run it every 5 minutes via cron. Then create and modify a secondary script for every time you must make a change to your ruleset for testing. Since cron will overwrite your rules every 5 minutes, its best to keep the rules you test also in their own script which you apply manually after every change you want to test. Once the final is working, remove cron.